# Python pick 20 random results from list

Tags: python, random

I would like to get 20 random results from the following list:

```
coordinates = [
  [20, 140], [40, 140], [60, 140], [80, 140], [100, 140], [120, 140],
  [20, 120], [40, 120], [60, 120], [80, 120], [100, 120], [120, 120],
  [20, 100], [40, 100], [60, 100], [80, 100], [100, 100], [120, 100],
  [20, 80], [40, 80], [60, 80], [80, 80], [100, 80], [120, 80],
  [20, 60], [40, 60], [60, 60], [80, 60], [100, 60], [120, 60],
  [20, 40], [40, 40], [60, 40], [80, 40], [100, 40], [120, 40]
]
```

I tried [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) but it returns `None`.

Comment: Tried it alreadt but does not work.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us the code that is not working.

Comment: When I use random.shuffle(coordinaten) it returns None.

Comment: Also with random.choice() it only returns one result, i need 20 results in a new list

Comment: `random.shuffle` returns nothing. He shuffles your source parameter directly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want 20 *unique* values in random order, use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
random.sample(coordinates, 20)
```

> ```
> random.sample(population, k)¶
> ```
>
> Return a *k* length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
>>> random.sample(coordinates, 20)
[[80, 60], [40, 100], [80, 100], [60, 80], [60, 100], [40, 60], [40, 80], [80, 120], [120, 140], [120, 100], [100, 80], [40, 120], [80, 140], [100, 140], [20, 80], [120, 80], [100, 100], [20, 40], [120, 120], [100, 120]]
```

---

You could use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) 20 times, but this will not be "unique"—elements may be duplicated, because one is randomly selected each time:

```
>>> [random.choice(coordinates) for _ in range(20)]
[[80, 80], [40, 140], [80, 140], [60, 60], [120, 100], [20, 120], [100, 80], [120, 100], [20, 60], [100, 120], [100, 40], [80, 80], [100, 80], [80, 120], [20, 40], [100, 80], [60, 80], [80, 140], [40, 40], [120, 40]]
```

Comment: If you need random choice with replacement, use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choices) (new in Python 3.6) instead of using `random.choice` in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be looking for [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) from the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html) library. You can use like this:

```
import random
my_new_list = random.sample(coordinates, 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle). Instead of returning a new shuffled list, `shuffle` modifies the list in place, which is why it wasn't returning anything.

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(coordinates)
result = coordinates[:20]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles the input parameter directly and returns nothing.

With [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random
random.shuffle(coordinates)[:20]
```

But it changes your source list. My opinion: it's not good.

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
import random
random.sample(coordinates, 20)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following recipe:

```
coordinaten = [[20, 140], [40, 140], [60, 140], [80, 140], [100, 140], [120, 140],
           [20, 120], [40, 120], [60, 120], [80, 120], [100, 120], [120, 120],
           [20, 100], [40, 100], [60, 100], [80, 100], [100, 100], [120, 100],
           [20, 80], [40, 80], [60, 80], [80, 80], [100, 80], [120, 80],
           [20, 60], [40, 60], [60, 60], [80, 60], [100, 60], [120, 60],
           [20, 40], [40, 40], [60, 40], [80, 40], [100, 40], [120, 40]]

import random

print(random.sample(coordinaten, 20))
```